# Am I handling SVG's correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a square `div` with two triangles drawn via SVGs within that looks like this :

[image]

I then have a button that once the `onClick` event is triggered it will add a class called `hidden` just basically has : `display: none; visibility: hidden;` to hide the bottom triangle, then displays two more triangles like so :

[image]

My current code looks like :
SVG to draw my triangle.

```
<svg id="triangle" width="100%" height="100%">
        <path d="M0,0 L680,0 L0,680 Z " id="top_triangle" class="o-top_main"></path>
    </svg>
```

Then the `image` for me to be able to use a background image :

```
   <svg style="position: absolute;">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="image_top" width="1" height="1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <image id="svg_img_top" xlink:href='http://41.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m8r9k312PE1qc6mk8o1_500.jpg' width="100" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

I've been drawing the SVG `path` like such `<path d="M0,0 L680,0 L0,680 Z "`. I've tried drawing an SVG triangle in photoshop, exporting out as an SVG then getting the path in the code and pasting in but the dimensions are never correct so I end up editing the path to the point where i've redrawn it anyway.

Is there anyway way I can draw an SVG triangle in Photoshop where I can then paste the path into my site without needing to change the `path` to the point where i've redrawn it?

My end site kind of looks similar to this :

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem or what are the specific goals you need to reach? General guidance is really too broad of a question to be asked here...

Comment: Ahh sorry! My bad. First time using SVGs and i've seen some really crazy svg animations and I thought they're must be an easier way to draw multiple triangles onto a page in SVG rather then changing the paths bit by bit to figure out where they go

Comment: No need to be sorry, your question as it is seems to be a poor match for this site. With some modifications you can probably have a pretty good question. Try to be more specific, focus on a specific problem you're having and you'll surely find help towards a solution.

Comment: i agree with that the question is to broard for this site, but the quality of this question is above what i usually see so i'll give a suggested answer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take a look at your first image here:

Now usually you allways want to create an viewBox on any svg element.
Width and height are usually set in css, but there are lots of cases where setting it in inline is better.

Now lets see your drawing 2 triangles with paths so and then adding another:

My suggestion is drawing 3 triangles then changing the color:
**Update:**
now with image url instead of colors. (the svg is getting quite complicated now)

```js
var bottom = document.getElementById("tri_tri");

bottom.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.style.fill = "yellow";
  this.style.stroke = "yellow";
});
```

```css
/**/

.triangleArt {
  width: 250px;
}
#tri_one {
  fill: firebrick;
}
#tri_two {
  fill: url(#image_top);
  stroke: url(#image_top);
}
#tri_tri {
  fill: url(#image_top);
  stroke: url(#image_top);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="triangleArt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image_top" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="250" height="156">
      <image id="svg_img_top" xlink:href='http://41.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m8r9k312PE1qc6mk8o1_500.jpg' x="0" y="0" width="250" height="156"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path id="tri_one" d="m0,100 100,-100, -100,0z" />
  <path id="tri_two" d="m100,0 0,100 -50,-50z" />
  <path id="tri_tri" d="m100,100 -50,-50 -50,50z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Brilliant! The code here looks a lot cleaner then what i'm doing at the moment. Thank you!

So basically, draw one `SVG` then have the paths draw multiple triangles that I can toggle with?

Comment: Yep my suggeston is just to draw 3 triangles and toggle the `fill` of the element. No need to have tree svg when you can draw tree paths in one svg element.

Comment: Dude, that's genius. Thanks a lot! I wasn't aware you could change the bg on an svg path. I thought the path was to draw one svg. Didn't knwo you could handle multiple paths in one svg

Comment: Ahh, that won't work for what i'm after. You see, where i've used colours. They'll be images. I used colours just because i'm terrible at photoshop. Could I have one image spanning two paths?

Comment: Let me try editing in the images paths you provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! Appreciate your help!